# Appium : Cannot continue script after app launch in real device

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to use '**uiautomatorviewer2**' as my dependency.

**Getting 'Cannot use apksigner tool for signing.'**

> Cannot use apksigner tool for signing. Defaulting to sign.jar.
>   Original error: Command
>   '/Users/tapan.khimani/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner
>   sign --key
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.pk8
>   --cert /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.x509.pem
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.3.0.apk'
>   exited with code 20;

Comment: Please add the capabilities you are sending to Appium. That would help in get the proper solution.

Comment: In addition to including your desired capabilities, you might also need to include your Java version you are running.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, thank you for reverting